# Doctrine's Many-To-Many Self-Referencing and reciprocity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many

By default, self-referencing `ManyToMany` relationships under Doctrine involve an owning side and an inverse side, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing).

Is there a way to implement a reciprocal association whithout difference between both sides?

Following the example in the docs:

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
     **/
    private $friends;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->friends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

So, adding `entity1` to `entity2`s `friends`  implies that `entity2` will be in `entity1`s friends.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve this problem, all depending on what the requirements for the "friends" relation are.

**Unidirectional**

A simple approach would be to use a unidirectional ManyToMany association, and treat it as if it where a bidirectional one (keeping both sides in sync):

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinTable(name="friends",
     *     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_a_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_b_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $friends;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->friends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFriends()
    {
        return $this->friends->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @param  User $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function addFriend(User $user)
    {
        if (!$this->friends->contains($user)) {
            $this->friends->add($user);
            $user->addFriend($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param  User $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function removeFriend(User $user)
    {
        if ($this->friends->contains($user)) {
            $this->friends->removeElement($user);
            $user->removeFriend($this);
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

When you call `$userA->addFriend($userB)`, `$userB` will be added to the friends-collection in `$userA`, and `$userA` will be added to the friends-collection in `$userB`.

It will also result in 2 records added to the "friends" table (1,2 and 2,1). While this can be seen as duplicate data, it will simplify your code a lot. For example when you need to find all friends of `$userA`, you can simply do:

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.friends f WHERE f.id = :userId
```

No need to check 2 different properties as you would with a bidirectional association.

**Bidirectional**

When using a bidirectional association the `User` entity will have 2 properties, `$myFriends` and `$friendsWithMe` for example. You can keep them in sync the same way as described above.

The main difference is that on a database level you'll only have one record representing the relationship (either 1,2 or 2,1). This makes "find all friends" queries a bit more complex because you'll have to check both properties.

You could of course still use 2 records in the database by making sure `addFriend()` will update both `$myFriends` and `$friendsWithMe` (and keep the other side in sync). This will add some complexity in your entities, but queries become a little less complex.

**OneToMany / ManyToOne**

If you need a system where a user can add a friend, but that friend has to confirm that they are indeed friends, you'll need to store that confirmation in the join-table. You then no longer have a ManyToMany association, but something like `User` <- OneToMany -> `Friendship` <- ManyToOne -> `User`.

You can read my blog-posts on this subject:

- [Doctrine 2: How to handle join tables with extra columns](http://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/doctrine-2-how-to-handle-join-tables-with-extra-columns)
- [More on one-to-many/many-to-one associations in Doctrine 2](http://future500.nl/articles/2013/09/more-on-one-to-manymany-to-one-associations-in-doctrine-2)

Comment: Unidirectional => Could not determine access type for property `...`

Comment: You need to map the `id` property. I've added it to the example (mapped as an integer, but it could be anything you like).

Comment: Very useful answer. For me the important part to add was `$user->addFriend($this);`.

Comment: When cloning this entity it didn't take the bidirectional links. But I had to add

"    public function __clone() {
        foreach($this->getFriends() as $thatFriend) {
            $thatFriend->addFriend($this);
        }
    }"