# I'm trying to model an ERD for a social platform

Tags: sql, database, erd

How do I implement a friend liking or commenting on my post?

I was told that having User_ID and Friend_User_ID as separate entities is redundant. How do I tie these up into one?

Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks

Comment: if you have a table that holds posts then you could create a table likes where you just store the primary id for the comment and the primary id of the user who liked it, and a table comments where you do the same but also add a comment field where the comment string is stored

Comment: Friend is still an User, so it's a simple relationship. Check my ERD below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, friend is still an user. Only the relationship with another user should be designed as a 'friendship' relationship between them (but that's not a thing you are asking for).
Considering this, the ERD would (in simplified way) look like this:

[image]

Like table would generally look the same.

**Edit #1:**

You can address Friendship for your ERD in many ways.
One of them would look like this:

[image]

You can either use composite key as I did or go with unique ID of Friendship itself.
Please take a look on good StackOverflow post here: 
[Doctrine's Many-To-Many Self-Referencing and reciprocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244816/doctrines-many-to-many-self-referencing-and-reciprocity)
It's described using PHP but should be easy to understand for any OOP coder.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. I have these entities in my model. What I was looking for is the 'Friendship' relationship. It would be great if you could help me with that. Thanks again

Comment: Hey, no problem. I've added what you've requested on seperate ERD so you can elaborate on it yourself. I've also added link to SO post that elaborate on this very well (and also uses User<>Friendship relationship).