# How to create a Doctrine2 Self-referencing Association with no hierarchy using YAML

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an "article" entity and I want to create an association with "related" articles without any hierarchy. Simply to be able to store the fact that one article is related to multiple others.

I went through [this reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) but the many-to-many self reflecting had no example using YAML.

What would be the right way to do design it?

This is my current entity:

```
ContentBundle\Entity\Article:
    type: entity
    table: articles
    repositoryClass: ContentBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        title:
            type: string
            length: 255
        content:
            type: text
        creationDate:
            type: datetime
            column: creation_date
        updateDate:
            type: datetime
            column: update_date
        state:
            type: string
            length: 255
            options:
                default: 'public'
    oneToOne:
        cover:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Image 
            joinColumn:
                name: image_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    oneToMany:
        notes:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Note
            mappedBy: article
        histories:
            targetEntity: HistoricalEntry
            mappedBy: article
        comments:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Comment
            mappedBy: article
        secrets:
            targetEntity: Secret
            mappedBy: article
    manyToOne:
        author:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\User
            inversedBy: articles
            joinColumn:
                name: user_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        world:
            targetEntity: WorldBundle\Entity\World
            inversedBy: articles
            joinColumn:
                name: world_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        category:
            targetEntity: WorldBundle\Entity\Category 
            inversedBy: articles
            joinColumn:
                name: category_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    manyToMany:
        tags:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Tag
            inversedBy: articles
            joinTable:
                name: articles_tags
                joinColumns:
                    article_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    tag_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
    inheritanceType: JOINED
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: template
        type: string
        length: 50
    discriminatorMap:
        article: Article
        person: Person
        location: Location
        organization: Organization 
        species: Species
    options:
        charset: utf8
        type: InnoDB
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: You can use the Doctrine examples for either ManyToMany one-directional or bi-directional, depending on your needs.  This answer has an excellent explanation for what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21335197/1307183 You

Comment: Thank you @JasonRoman I guess that I would need a unidirectional ManyToMany association, and treat it as if it were a bidirectional one (keeping both sides in sync). I can see the answer in the Annotation format but I am not sure how to translate it in yml.

Comment: Just use Doctrine's documentation which has the ManyToMany uni-directional example in YAML. Let me know of you have trouble with that.