# Symfony Doctrine mapping inside one Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, mapping, entity

I had one `class User` which is also an Entity type. I need to store information about which user can send a message to another one. My conceptual solution is:
- to make a database table with two columns, except unique `id` of course (`id_sender, id_recipient`)
- the next step should be to map my `class User` to that table (maybe using `@joinTable` annotation)
What is a good practice for thinks like that? I know I should use the doctrine (as a higher abstraction layer). Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you asking how to associate entities? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

Comment: not exactly, i already studied how to associate entities, but still i'm not quite sure how to make the associations in this specific case.

Comment: I guess you can use the same approach described in [`Doctrine's Many-To-Many Self-Referencing and reciprocity`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21335197/853360)

Comment: Yes, that's what i was asking about! Thank you M Khalid.