# Symfony ManyToMany relation on entities of same type

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I am trying to solve what I call the "sibling dilemma":
I have an entity person that can have siblings, which of course are persons, too.

Therefore I have created the following entity:

```
/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PersonRepository")
 */
class Person {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Person", inversedBy="ref_siblings")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="siblings",  
     *  joinColumns={ @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person", referencedColumnName="id") },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={ @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sibling", referencedColumnName="id") }
     * )
     */
     private $siblings;

    /**
     * @param Person $person
     */
    public function addSibling(Person $person)
    {
        if ($this->siblings->contains($person)) {
            return;
        }

        $this->siblings->add($person);
        $person->addSibling($this);
    }

    /**
     * @param Person $person
     */
    public function removeSibling(Person $person)
    {
        if (!$this->siblings->contains($person)) {
            return;
        }

        $this->siblings->removeElement($person);
        $person->removeSibling($this);
    }
    ...
}
```

So by adding a sibling to a person I can successfully store the relation in the doctrine created relation table:

```
mysql> select * from siblings;
+--------+---------+
| person | sibling |
+--------+---------+
|   681  |     715 |
+--------+---------+
```

So far so good.

However it is not covering my request as I like. The current solution shows a sibling for person 681 but not for person 715.
I need to have something that also stores the relation on the inverse side, as person 715 has also a sibling - which is person 681.

Is there a convenient way to store the relation like so:

```
mysql> select * from siblings;
+--------+---------+
| person | sibling |
+--------+---------+
|   681  |     715 |
|   715  |     681 |
+--------+---------+
```

The only workaround I've found was doing the following in the PersonController class:

```
  foreach($person->getSiblings() as $sibling) {
      $sibling->addSibling($person);
      $em->persist($sibling);
  }
  $em->flush();
```

However this does not solve the problem, if I try to remove a sibling.

Comment: maybe this helps you setting it up correct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244816/doctrines-many-to-many-self-referencing-and-reciprocity another way would be to have another entity for instance "Sibling" where you relate both entites manytoone

Comment: Also your Solution seems pretty good, just when you remove you have to do the same on remove