# ORO crm ManyToMany self reference association in core entity

Tags: orocrm

Wanted to ask opinion on solution for current update. Few conditions and use case:

1. Friends is extended manytomany property of core UserEntity from UserBundle
2. When we add friend, owner entity should also appear in child entity
3. When we remove friend, friends should also be un assinged from association with owning side

My solution is to use Event subscriber on onFlush even, maybe anyone has a better approach?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection;
use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;

class UserEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::onFlush,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param OnFlushEventArgs $args
     */
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $uow = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork();

        $updates = array_merge(
            $uow->getScheduledCollectionUpdates(),
            $uow->getScheduledCollectionDeletions()
        );

        array_walk(
            $updates,
            fn (PersistentCollection $collection) => $this->processFriendsOnFlush($collection, $args)
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param PersistentCollection $collection
     * @param OnFlushEventArgs     $args
     */
    private function processFriendsOnFlush(PersistentCollection $collection, OnFlushEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $mapping = $collection->getMapping();

        if ($collection->getOwner() instanceof User && $mapping['fieldName'] === 'friends')
        {
            $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
            /** @var User $ownerUser */
            $ownerUser = $collection->getOwner();
            $snapshotFriends = $collection->getSnapshot();
            $updatedFriends = $collection->getValues();

            if (count($updatedFriends) > 0 && $snapshotFriends !== $updatedFriends) {
                array_walk($updatedFriends, fn(User $friend) => $this->bindFriendAssociation($entityManager, $ownerUser, $friend));
            }

            if (count($snapshotFriends) > 0) {
                array_walk($snapshotFriends, fn(User $friend) => $this->removeFriendAssociation($entityManager, $ownerUser, $friend));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bind friend association to keep bidirectional relation on adding new friend user
     *
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     * @param User          $ownerUser
     * @param User          $friend
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     */
    private function bindFriendAssociation(EntityManager $entityManager, User $ownerUser, User $friend): void
    {
        if (!$friend->getFriends()->contains($ownerUser)) {
            $friend->addFriend($ownerUser);
            $entityManager->persist($friend);
            $entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSet($entityManager->getClassMetadata(get_class($friend)), $friend);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove friend user association to keep bidirectional relation on remove friend user from child
     *
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     * @param User          $ownerUser
     * @param User          $friend
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     */
    private function removeFriendAssociation(EntityManager $entityManager, User $ownerUser, User $friend): void
    {
        if ($friend->getFriends()->contains($ownerUser)) {
            $friend->removeFriend($ownerUser);
            $entityManager->persist($friend);
            $entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSet($entityManager->getClassMetadata(get_class($friend)), $friend);
        }
    }
}
```

Same how I add ManyToMany association:

```php
$this->extendExtension->addManyToManyRelation(
            $schema,
            $schema->getTable('oro_user'),
            'friends',
            $schema->getTable('oro_user'),
            ['last_name', 'first_name'],
            ['last_name', 'first_name'],
            ['last_name', 'first_name'],
            [
                'extend' => [
                    'owner' => ExtendScope::OWNER_CUSTOM,
                    'target_title' => ['id'],
                    'target_detailed' => ['id'],
                    'target_grid' => ['id'],
                    'cascade' => ['persist'],
                ],
                'dataaudit' => ['auditable' => true],
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the relation is bidirectional, and you have initialized the ArrayCollection for both properties in a entity constructor, as the documentation states:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional.

And you have `add*`, `remove*` methods with the proper implementation, like:

```php
    public function addFriend(User $user)
    {
        if (!$this->friends->contains($user)) {
            $this->friends->add($user);
            $user->addFriend($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFriend(User $user)
    {
        if ($this->friends->contains($user)) {
            $this->friends->removeElement($user);
            $user->removeFriend($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

If it's the code generated by OroPlatform, you can affect it by writing a custom `Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Tools\GeneratorExtensions\AbstractEntityGeneratorExtension`. A good example is [Oro\Bundle\EntitySerializedFieldsBundle\Tools\GeneratorExtensions\SerializedDataGeneratorExtension](https://github.com/oroinc/OroEntitySerializedFieldsBundle/blob/master/Tools/GeneratorExtensions/SerializedDataGeneratorExtension.php).

For you, it would be something like:

```php
# ...
public function generate(array $schema, ClassGenerator $class): void
{
    $method = $class->getMethod('addFriend');
    $method->setBody('if (!$this->friends->contains($user)) {
        $this->friends->add($user);
        $user->addFriend($this);
    }');

    $method = $class->getMethod('removeFriend');
    $method->setBody('if ($this->friends->contains($user)) {
        $this->friends->removeElement($user);
        $user->removeFriend($this);
    }');
}
# ...
```

And don't forget to [register the generator in a service container](https://github.com/oroinc/OroEntitySerializedFieldsBundle/blob/4f6651d424a38cb951e34fc3facb82e849460ce0/Resources/config/services.yml#L16-L21) with the `oro_entity_extend.entity_generator_extension` tag.

Comment: Yes but that's in context of doctrine solution when you own entity and can update methods. That would have been best solution if possible.
However I describe case in context of OroCRM and core entity, that is not possible to update directly.

Comment: You can add extra fields for the core entity using schema migrations. Accessors for these fields are generated in the cache, `./var/cache/prod/oro_entities/Extend/Entity` folder. And with the migration options you can control what is generated there. See https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/entities/extend-entities/associations/#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: I'm a bit newbee at Oro. But as far as I've seen, as I need self reference, so I can't configure bidirectional relation on the same field.
And extending UserEntity is failing due that it's already Extended in UserBundle.
Maybe you know of a good doc to check how it can be configured with self referece?
As extend asstiation do not mention any of such case :)
I've already a extednded manytomany relation in my migration, but without inversed side, as it can't be the same property, as my target is to have single property in UserEntity that would be bidirectional

Comment: "it can't be the same property, as my target is to have single property in UserEntity that would be bidirectional " - According to the doc, there should be two properties https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing

Comment: Yes but my target is to have single property and not "friendsWithMe" and "myFriends".
And it's simple enough to do having access to Entity directly (as samples in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244816/doctrines-many-to-many-self-referencing-and-reciprocity).
My listener only simulates same logic inside event listener.

Comment: Now I see. The alternative approach is to affect the code generation. See \Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Tools\GeneratorExtensions\AbstractEntityGeneratorExtension implementations, like \Oro\Bundle\EntitySerializedFieldsBundle\Tools\GeneratorExtensions\SerializedDataGeneratorExtension

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of such generator

Comment: Hmm nice approach thx would defiantly check it

Comment: Hmm maybe you can also help.
I've tried you're suggestion and generated entity successfully.
(Just a note: I had to use ` AbstractAssociationEntityGeneratorExtension`).

However when I add "friend" from form It's not set from that entity.
And `addFriend` and `removeFriend` methods, are never fired for some reason.
When I `dump($this->friends)` in generated `getFriends()` method, collection is always empty, while I see that it already has associated entities. 
Generated class is at path `var/cache/dev/oro_entities/Extend/Entity/EX_OroUserBundle_User.php` with updated methods.

Comment: Also added in my first question sample on how I add association.

Comment: Forms are a bit tricky when working with collections. They can use the set* method instead of add*/remove*. I don't remember when it happens, and it's hard to find it without debugging. You can debug it to find the reason, or update the setter to make it work properly as well.